# How to create an <p:inputmask> for a range of numbers

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces

I want to mask an input text field in a dialog, I am using primefaces 3.5 SNAPSHOT. The following works great for me except I want to include number 10 within the mask.

```
  <p:dialog id="inputDlg" modal="true" widgetVar="inputDlgWV">
     <p:inputMask id="ageInput" mask="9" placeHolder=" " value="#{bean.age}"/>
  </p:dialog>
```

I tried **f:validateRegex** with a pattern, it validates correctly but it doesn't mask the input, my main goal is to mask and allow only numbers from 0-10. Thanks for your help.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? You would like to have Primefaces' 2 underscores in an input field? Or you need custom JS validation? Maybe spinner would be a more fit solution?

Comment: I need to limit what the user can insert inside an inputText component. The user should only insert one number from 0-10.

Comment: Your code working as expected.You are saying `user should only insert one number from 0-10`. You are not understanding number range conecept correctly.Cause when you specify`0-10` this `10` will be considered as `1` and `0` in `0-9` pattern.

Comment: @SrinivasR I totally understand what my code is doing, my question is very can you get an inputText to accept one number form the following set (0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10).

Comment: InputNumber of Prime faces extensions is an option. http://fractalsoft.net/primeext-showcase-mojarra/sections/inputNumber/basicUsage.jsf

Answer (score 2):

According to the [Masked Input Plugin for jQuery](http://digitalbush.com/projects/masked-input-plugin/), on which Primefaces' component `<p:inputMask>` is based, the `mask` property accepts `9` as a digit, `a` as a letter, `*` as either of the two, `?` as optional user input and anything else as a predefined text.

In this light your desired attribute will be `mask="9?9"`. Of course, it will accepts numbers in the range 0-99. In case you would like a strict 0-10 range, you would need to bind an additional handler for the `keydown` event, something like:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#input-mask").keydown(function(e) {
        var key = (e.keyCode ? e.keyCode : e.which);
        if (!((key == 46) || (key == 8))) {
            if ((key < 48) || (key > 57)) {
                event.preventDefault();
            } else {
                var s = $(this).val();
                var l = s.length;
                if((l >= 2) || ((l == 1) && !((s == '1') && (key == 48)))) {
                    event.preventDefault();
                }
            }
        }
    });
});
```

To my taste, this won't be user-friendly enough and in your place I would have chosen [`<p:spinner>`](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/input/spinner.xhtml) instead.

Comment: Have you succeeded with finding a solution?